# Why is this Container Div Breaking My Design

Tags: css, wordpress

Im trying to put these 2 elements in a container, the read more button, and another floating button, and i want them both to float left. When i run the code, the elements are not inside the div and is like 200px below the container. Why?

```
<div class="readMore_Container">                          
    <?php the_content('Read More  &raquo;'); ?>
    <div class="postCounter">#200</div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.readMore_Container {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: ;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: would be great if you could provide us a fiddle..

Comment: Position `nothing` isn't a very healthy way of writing CSS. Also what's the result of the `the_content` function?

Comment: thats the code i see in place for the read more button

Comment: can you share your page URL?

Comment: what does the output of `the_content` look like in your case?

Answer (score 1):

PLease remove the_content and use as per below

```
<div class="readMore_Container">                          
    <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
    <div class="postCounter">#200</div>
</div>
```

Beacuse there is missing div in your content area.

Answer (score 0):

Use span instead of div. It will show both the elements in one line.

```
<div class="readMore_Container">                          
    <span><?php the_content('Read More  &raquo;'); ?></span>
    <span>#200</span>
</div>
```

The difference between span and div is that a span element is in-line and usually used for a small chunk of HTML inside a line (such as inside a paragraph) whereas a div (division) element is block-line (which is basically equivalent to having a line-break before and after it) and used to group larger chunks of code.